# HttpClient how to track requests

Tags: java, httpclient, office365

The thing is that I want to register an account from code (Java). I have this form to sign up:

https://portal.microsoftonline.com/Signup/MainSignUp15.aspx?&OfferId=55A1B852-7BB9-4d78-AE46-0D1B213D1725&dl=LITEPACK_P2&Country=US&culture=en-us&ali=1

Of course, here we have a captcha, that's why I don't want to register automatic accounts. I just want to register from code and I will enter the captcha somehow.

Let's think there is no captcha.

I want to register this using `HttpClient`, but I have no idea how. I really don't know how to to do it, I was thinking about using `httpPost` with the correct namevalues, but Where do I have to do the Post?, to which URL?.

Maybe you can point me to a tool to track the course of my request or How should I do this?

Thank you in advance, any tip would be appretiated.